# Dialog box disappearing on right click in data grid view cells

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

I have created a grid view using Windows forms.I have also provided a context strip menu that contains the copy option on right click.

However,the dialog box itself disappears on right clicking in one of the cells and comes back again on a left click. Am I missing something ? The problem was however solved if I make the Top Most Property of the dialog box true.But I do not want to make the dialog box always on top.

```
private void mnuCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (row >= 0 && col >= 0)
    {
        Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, ErrorDetailsDataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.ToString());
    }
}

private void ErrorDetailsDataGridView_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{            
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && e.ColumnIndex != -1 && e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        row = e.RowIndex;
        col = e.ColumnIndex;
        ContextMenuStrip mnu = new ContextMenuStrip();
        ToolStripMenuItem mnuCopy = new ToolStripMenuItem("Copy");
        mnuCopy.Click += new EventHandler(this.mnuCopy_Click);
        mnu.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { mnuCopy });
        if (ErrorDetailsDataGridView.CurrentCell != ErrorDetailsDataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[col])
        {
            ErrorDetailsDataGridView.CurrentCell = ErrorDetailsDataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[col];
        }
        ErrorDetailsDataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[col].ContextMenuStrip = mnu;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the _dialog box_? do you mean that the form is a child of another form, and it disappear on right click?

Comment: yes it is a child of another form

Comment: Try setting the `Owner` of the "dialog" when you `Show()` it by passing in the Form containing the DataGridView: `frmDialog.Show(this);`